# Moving a lot of data data from HDFS to HDFS

Tags: multithreading, hadoop, hdfs

I get a lot of data from different providers with different formats and I'd like to move daily these data to a common place with a common format. So, I should copy about X Terabytes of data daily.

I want to avoid any transformation right now, so, I just want to move X Terabytes of data from my HDFS to another place in my HDFS. This could take a long time, Does someone know about how I could move data quickly?? I have been thinking about multithreading, could it work? I'd try to have many threads copying files simultaneously. Right now, there's just a thread.

Comment: If you are moving why not use `hadoop fs -mv` command?

Answer (score 0):

Try distcp, which is a tool used for large inter/intra-cluster copying.

See http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/distcp.html